# Can not update view on angular4 by component intraction through service

Tags: angular, angular-services

Hello I am trying to call method of another component(ProductComponent) from a component(HeaderComponent). for this i used a service. I created a service ProductService which is a shared service amoung these components. but I doesnt update the view when the variable value is changed in service please help. here is the code

*productservice.service.ts*

```
  import { Injectable, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
  @Injectable()
  export class ProductServiceService {

    contentSource = new Subject();
    str = 'initial';
    content$ = this.contentSource.asObservable();
    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }
    setData(str){
      this.str = str;
      console.log(str);
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
    getData(){
      return this.str;
    }

  }
```

*header.component.ts*

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductsComponent, ProductServiceService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

 constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,private _http: Http,  private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef, private sharedService: ProductServiceService) 
 {
}    
ngOnInit() {
}
    newProudutsData(slug: string){
    this.sharedService.contentSource.next("echo");
    this.sharedService.setData('Done Calling');
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

*product.component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-products',
    templateUrl: './products.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./products.component.css'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
    providers: [ProductServiceService],
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnDestroy {
    slug='';
    subscription: Subscription;
    testdata = 'abcd';
    constructor(private _http: Http, private sharedService: ProductServiceService) 
    {
            this.testdata = sharedService.getData();
            console.log("received222");
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

the final output I am getting when the page loads is initial but when the method 
newProudutsData() is called it should be changed to Done Calling.

------ edited --------

product component is defined in header component by  which calls prodcut component when route

```
{
            path: 'products/:id',
            component: ProductsComponent
 },
```

is called.

Comment: show   ./products.component.html code

Comment: and ./products.component.html

Answer (score 1):

The components have their own services and they are not connected. You should extract service to the module. When you specify service to the component you make it local only to that component meaning you have 2 different instances of service instead of one and they dont share data with each other. I recommned using augury in chrome deb tools to see the dependency injection

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

}

 @Component({
    selector: 'app-products',
    templateUrl: './products.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./products.component.css'],
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnDestroy {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ProductsComponent , HeaderComponent  ]
  providers: [
     ProductServiceService
  ]
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Use behaviorSubject instead of subject

```
    contentSource = new BehaviorSubject('');
```

Subject doesn't save previous value BehaviorSubject does.
And if source emit something but You were not subscribe at that time you will loose this value.

[created Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TU0HOFFYrws0fY2ECQSK?p=preview)

Comment: the service is defined in `app.module.ts` in providers array. I tried to remove them from both the components but nothing works

Comment: @NaveenSingh ok. Thouts that they are parent and child. Then you need to use not Subject but behaviorSubject

Comment: when the category changed the function newProudutsData() get called which then call setData method of service the setData set the variable value but in productComponent the variable value is called (getData) in constructor but the constructor is only firstly called when the page gets load. but when I am on the product page and change the category it did'nt get reflected because constructor is not called any solution to that.

Comment: @NaveenSingh i will create plunker. cause you messed up a lot

Comment: solved https://plnkr.co/edit/LwIPB52seD25PINErekY?p=info still the constructor is called once but the ngOnInit method is called every time the url changes so i changed the variable value on that event. It is differ from the workflow I was trying earlier but I reached my end result. thank you.